# 'I stayed up late reading last night' vs. 'I stayed up reading late last night'

Tags: word-order

Which of the following sentences can I say?

1. 'I stayed up late reading last night.'
2. 'I stayed up reading late last night.'

If they are both grammatical, are there any differences between them?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Both sentences are valid, but they mean slightly different things. You may be interested in our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour); please be sure to complete their site tour and review their [help center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) for tips on how to write a good, answerable question.

Comment: I'd go with the latter one. The first one sounds as if you were up late because you were reading the night itself!

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use "I stayed up late reading last night" because I see the "late" as an attribute of staying up, not reading. I also wonder if that shouldn't be punctuated as "I stayed up late, reading, last night" to clarify the sentence.

It reminds me of that example "The panda bear eats shoots and leaves" as opposed to "The panda bear eats, shoots and leaves". :-)

Answer (score 0):

'I stayed up late reading last night.'
'I stayed up reading late last night.'
 Well, in my candid opinion,the both are not the same .it's more appropriate to say 'I stayed up reading late last night.'stayed up is a phrasal verb ,meaning not sleeping or being awake.So,you stayed up engaging in the activity of reading at late hour.It's the action(verb) of reading that keeps you awake late.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion,
I think this issue is related to misplaced and dangling modifiers.
I would change the word order to clarify what i mean.
I will adhere to this basic order "Who, what, how, where, when, why".

I stayed up late last night to read.
or 
To read, I stayed up late last night.

However, if the meaning is "I was a reading and that kept me wake up all-night", I might write it as " I read last night that I stayed up late.

Comment: I stayed up late last night, reading this book.  means i was reading this book that make me awake up all-night.  The act of reading is prior to staying up act.

Comment: I stayed up late last night to read. means that I did not sleep to read. The act of staying up is before the act of reading.